# Matlab interpolation of 4D scattered data

Tags: matlab, 3d, grid, interpolation, 4d

We have a 195x4 (double) matrix: `A=[X Y Z temp]`, when ploted with `scatter3(A(:,1), A(:,2), A(:,3),30, A(:,4), 'filled' )` gives something like this:
[image]

Now we want to generate a 'cube' colored with the interpolation of the `temp=A(:,4)` vector data.
So far we have tried [interp3](https://la.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html)

```
% Base Grid
[Xm Ym Zm] = meshgrid(A(:,1), A(:,2), A(:,3)); 
% Grid Refinement
[Xq,Yq,Zq] = meshgrid(xmin:dx:xmax, ymin:dy:ymax, zmin:dz:zmax);
Aq = interp3(Xm,Ym,Zm,A(:,4),Xq,Yq,Zq);
```

Returns the following error:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
The number of input coordinate arrays does not equal the number of dimensions
(NDIMS) of these arrays.

Error in interp3 (line 144)
            F = griddedInterpolant(X, Y, Z, V, method,extrap);

Error in PDGEM_MT (line 112)
Aq = interp3(Xm,Ym,Zm,A(:,4),Xq,Yq,Zq);
```

So I think, may be a bad implementation and/or a wrong interpretation of the problem.
How to generate a 'cube'of that space colored with the volume interpolation of `A(:,4)`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an scattered dataset.

`interp3` does only work if your data points are in meshgrid format [read this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html#bt2rbzl-1-XYZ). The short description of this function is `Interpolation for 3-D gridded data in meshgrid format`

Instead you can use `griddata` which works for scattered data [read this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html#bvkwume-method). The short description is `Interpolate 2-D or 3-D scattered data`.

Example:

```
X = rand(100,1);
Y = rand(100,1);
Z = rand(100,1);
C = rand(100,1);

figure
scatter3(X, Y, Z,30, C, 'filled' )

[Xm, Ym, Zm] = meshgrid(min(X):.01:max(X), min(Y):.01:max(Y), min(Z):.01:max(Z)); 

Cm = griddata(X,Y,Z,C,Xm,Ym,Zm);

figure
scatter3(Xm(:), Ym(:), Zm(:), 30, Cm(:), 'filled' )
```

Data points:
[image: data]

Interpolated:
[image: gridded]

Comment: worked like a charm. Vielen Dank, Sie sind sehr nett.